# PHP: есть ли способ сгенерировать путь до элемента массива на любой уровень вложенности в цикле?

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, динамические-массивы, преобразование

Массив можно раскрыть на какой-то уровень вложенности циклом. foreach($arr as $key => $value).

Но если он может поступить с разным уровнем вложенности, например,

[1] => [2] = [3] или [1] => [2] = [3] => [4] => [5], то цикл или два цикла не помогут. Элементов может быть либо больше, либо меньше.

А если в массиве 100 ключей? Не писать же $arr[$next][$next][$next][$next] и так далее 100 раз.

Добраться до произвольного элемента на глубину, при том, что не известно, будет ли он вообще, можно через рекурсию, но неужели нет способа обойтись без нее?

Comment: Рекурсия - the only way

Comment: просто странно, что, например, html можно сгенерировать склеиванием строки, по всякому, хоть 1000 дивов, а $arr'[0][1]' не работает

Comment: Есть вариант сделать через eval, но он не даст варианта проверки доступности ключа

Comment: "*склеиванием строки*" --- в PHP конкатенация тоже есть.... как можно сравнивать конкатенацию и доступ к массиву по вложенности? Перпендикулрные вещи

Comment: `$arr[0][1]` вполне работает, почему нет? кавычки откуда взяли там?

Comment: если вы знаете "путь" до чего ищите, то этот путь надо итерировать, и обращаться к ключам искомого массива.

Comment: @teran не `$arr[0][1]` а `$arr'[0][1]'`

Comment: А вот смотрите, мне нужно обработать массив с вложенностью. в 1000 ключей, как мне прописать путь  до 1000-го ключа? чтобы это было оптимально.. читаемо..

Comment: вы знаете конкретный путь или вам все перебрать надо?

Comment: притом, я не знаю 1000 у меня будет ключей или 1001

Comment: до 1000 ключа ......читаемо......... это две противоположные вещи........ никто в здравом уме таким извращением не занимается

Comment: Вы лучше задачу свою скажите, кажется вы делаете какую-то шнягу))

Comment: вложенный массив это по сути дерево. Деревья обходить можно либо в глубину либо в ширину. Можно рекурсией а можно через стек. Пока что не ясно. что вы вообще делаете

Comment: )) детали задачи не могу сказать увы.. но я собираю дерево, которое может быть любым, могут добавить элементов, убавить в любых вариациях.. пригодился бы способ обратиться к любому элементу массива максимально абстрактно.. а я из того, что нахожу - не нашел ничего подходящего. Хочется обойтись без рекурсии.. Просто интересно, можно ли по-другому..

Comment: @teran гуглю стек, но объяснения, как ключи этим перебирать не нахожу..

Comment: как я написал выше - можно eval'ом но без проверки наличия ключа. ( https://onlinephp.io/c/9d346 )

Comment: а чeм плоха рекурсия?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский традиционно рекурсия плоха ограничением глубины вложенности и скоростью работы. Но тут не ясно что автору вообще надо. Мне кажется ему не требуется обходить все элементы массива, а только добраться "по адресу".

Comment: Это очевидно не массив и не стек, а список\двусвязный список, где каждый элемент хранит ссылку на следующего (или\и родителя).

Comment: @u_mulder при чем тут двусвязный список? человек просто путь до листа указал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не совсем ясно что вы пытаетесь сделать, но ощущение что на входе вы имеет массив индексов по которому надо пройти, а-ля `0,1,10,3,5`, что было бы эквивалентно доступу по пути `$arr[0][1][10][3][5]`.

Если такой путь у вас имеется в качестве массив, то в в цикле его перебираете и двигаетесь к элементу

```
$data = [...]; // исходный массив
$value = getElement($data, [0,1,10,3,5]);
print_r($value);

function getElement(&$data, array $path){
    $item = &$data;
    foreach ($path as $index) {
        if (is_array($item) && array_key_exists($item, $index)) {
            $item = &$item[$index];
        } else {
            throw new Exception('path does not exist');
        }
    } 
    return $item;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Это именно то, что я искал, только не знал, что так можно сделать!